# Custom POCO-Objects to table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Currently I used inherited DbContext-Classes containing DbSet<T> members to store POCO objects into database. This works fine for 'compile-time-known' classes and their structures.

Now I have a class like

```
public class ResourceSet
{
    public long Id
    {
        get;
        set;

    }
    public long OwnerId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double[] Resources
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and would like to store it into a database-scheme:

Id, OwnerId, Res_1, Res_2, Res_3, ... (depending on size of Resources, which will be fixed during start-up of program).

- Currently I use CTP5 of EFCodeFirst
- DbSet<ResourceSet> fails of course. It does not support indexed properties.
- I would like to avoid the .edmx files

My question:

Is it possible to create a proxy/wrapper/transformation class, which maps the Resources Array into the Res_X columns. Do you have a hint within document where I can start?

LINQ for searching into 'Id' and 'OwnerId' shall be still possible, for Resources, it is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If `Resources` are never needed in a Linq query you can map it to a string backing property and then save that back in the database.

```
public double[] Resources
{
    get
    {
        var result = from r in ResourceString.Split(new string[] {";"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                     select double.Parse(r);

        return result.ToArray();
    }
    set
    {

        ResourceString = string.Empty;
        foreach (var d in value)
        {
            ResourceString += d + ";";
        }
    }
}

private string ResourceString
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

If you update your Entity Framework to the latest version (trough NuGet) and specify Resources as not mapped everything should work.

Comment: `ResourceString` should be `public` to be mapped, shouldn't it?

Comment: Quite clever solution! Thanks for hint. But I'd like to have the values as columns... I think I will directly use DbConnection for this issue and skip EF. Or is there a more clever way, avoiding the creation of Sql-Statements